Terraform AWS EC2 how to login with ssh pub file
Here's the terraform snippet
resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_sg" {
  name = "ec2-access"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    from_port = 22
    to_port   = 22
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]  # Allow SSH from anywhere (adjust for security)
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]  # Allow all outbound traffic (adjust for security)
  }
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "ssh-key" {
  key_name   = "ssh-key"
  public_key = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1..."
}

# EC2 Instance in Public Subnet
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami           = "ami-04b70fa74e45c3917" # Noble Numbat 24.04 LTS
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name         = "ssh-key"
}

And the terraform apply command creates the EC2 without error.
But then I try to ssh into the machine with ssh -i "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" <ec2 public address>
It gives error:

The authenticity of host 'ip.add.re.ss (ip.add.re.ss)' can't be established. ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:Q47dOukdKpdYhysUMwAEkxkIyz8AcGGawdx9fYjHxH4.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ip.add.re.ss' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
tata@ip.add.re.ss: Permission denied (publickey).

I guess I am misconfiguring the EC2?

You need to specify the login as <username>@<ip.add.re.ss> which in your case should probably be ubuntu@<ip.add.re.ss>.

The AMI ID says that it's a Ubuntu Linux, which means the default user name is ubuntu. That also means that the entire command should be:
ssh -i "~/.ssh/id_rsa" ubuntu@<ec2 public address>

The list of default users for different types of AMIs is in the AWS docs.

I just tried, still same error


Updated the answer, you need the private key actually. The public one goes on to the EC2 instance.

Yes you are right thanks so much! Private keyfile is called id_rsa by default, no need for priv.
Final command:
ssh -i "~/.ssh/id_rsa" ubuntu@<ec2 pub ip>
